# API in numbers?

Tags: api

does anyone knows how many functions Wordpress has? I mean, are the more used functions around 100 or more than 200?

ps: I am trying to build a catalog of the API and wrap it behind a visual programming language; so I'd love to know how much work I am facing ;-)

thanks,
guenter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From quick run of [phploc](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc) as of current stable version (4.0) there are 2662 functions in WordPress core.

```
Structure
  Namespaces                                         0
  Interfaces                                         1
  Traits                                             0
  Classes                                          241
    Abstract Classes                                 4 (1.66%)
    Concrete Classes                               237 (98.34%)
  Methods                                         2842
    Scope
      Non-Static Methods                          2552 (89.80%)
      Static Methods                               290 (10.20%)
    Visibility
      Public Methods                              2571 (90.46%)
      Non-Public Methods                           271 (9.54%)
  Functions                                       2662
    Named Functions                               2662 (100.00%)
    Anonymous Functions                              0 (0.00%)
  Constants                                        557
    Global Constants                               541 (97.13%)
    Class Constants                                 16 (2.87%)
```

Comment: I got 2533. Probably difference is in wp-content folder I excluded.